# Syntax error in EC2 Image Builder component

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, github-actions

I was writing terraform code for ec2 image builder component. And getting such errors:

```
CmdExecution: Stderr: which: no sw_vers in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
sudo: unknown user: mkdir
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

The code looks like this:

```
"phases":
- "name": "build"
  "steps":
  - "action": "ExecuteBash"
    "inputs":
      "commands":
      - "export RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT='1'"
      - "yum install -y jq"
      - "export RUNNER_CFG_PAT=ghp_fsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfd"
      - "curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/actions/runner/main/scripts/create-latest-svc.sh
        | bash -s -- -s githubuser/githubrepo -n githubrunner -l prod"
    "name": "example"
    "onFailure": "Continue"
"schemaVersion": 1
```

Previously I thought that it's because of root user execution so I added this line:

```
"export RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT='1'"
```

but event though that is not working
Do you have some ideas how to troubleshoot that

PS. terraform code:

```
resource "aws_imagebuilder_component" "example" {
  data = yamlencode({
    phases = [{
      name = "build"
      steps = [{
        action = "ExecuteBash"
        inputs = {
          commands = ["export RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT='1'", "yum install -y jq", "export RUNNER_CFG_PAT=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", "curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/actions/runner/main/scripts/create-latest-svc.sh | bash -s -- -s githubuser/githubrepo -n githubrunner -l prod"]
        }
        name      = "example"
        onFailure = "Continue"
      }]
    }]
    schemaVersion = 1.0
  })
  name     = "example33"
  platform = "Linux"
  version  = "1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Looking at `sudo: unknown user: mkdir` and your script(esp the part `sudo -u ${svc_user} mkdir runner`), it seems like `${svc_user}` variable is empty.

Comment: @Riz thank you! that's working now. I just changed "curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/actions/runner/main/scripts/create-latest-svc.sh | bash -s -- -s githubuser/githubrepo -n githubrunner -l prod -u root" then it worked. So but I wanted to mark your answer as a correct one and could you write an answer, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have much knowlege of terraform but looking at your code, it looked like you had missed initializing `svc_user` which was used by your script to do various stuff e.g create a directory where it used to fail and as the `sv_user` was 'null'. It would run `sudo -u ${svc_user} mkdir runner` as `sudo -u  mkdir runner` meaning do something as user `mkdir`.
It seems like you are passing `root` as `svc_user` now which has resolved your issue.